# After adding the line "from qgis.core import QgsApplication", the exe application does not work

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I am testing a simple PyQGIS application. When I add the line "from qgis.core import QgsApplication" and make an exe via pyinstaller, the application crashes with an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 3, in 
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in
> exec_module File "qgis\core_*init*_.py", line 25, in 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtPositioning'

```
import sys
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel
from qgis.core import QgsApplication

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Mapová prezeračka ---  Pebieha načítanie dát ...")
        self.init_gui()
        self.show()

    def init_gui(self):
        self.formular = QWidget()
        layoutFormulara = QHBoxLayout()
        self.formular.setLayout(layoutFormulara)
        boxLayout1 = QHBoxLayout()
        boxLayout2 = QHBoxLayout()

        layoutFormulara.addStretch()
        layoutFormulara.addLayout(boxLayout1)
        layoutFormulara.addLayout(boxLayout2)
        layoutFormulara.addStretch()

        self.label1 = QLabel("Hello")
        boxLayout1.addWidget(self.label1)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.formular)

def main():
    # vytvoriť hlavné okno
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()

    # Spustiť aplikáciu
    try:
        retval = app.exec_()
        # Ukončiť aplikáciu
        sys.exit(retval)  # toto vždy vyvolá SystemExit
    except SystemExit:
        print("sys.exit() fungovalo podľa očakávania")
    except:
        print("Niečo sa strašne pokazilo")  # bola vznesená iná výnimka


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main()
```

I using Python Interpreter C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\python.exe and QGis 3.22 and IDE Pycharm 2022.2.2

When I comment out the line "from qgis.core import QgsApplication" the application window starts normally after creating the EXE. I have a larger application, just this small test, I'm trying pyinstaller.

Comment: What's your pyinstaller invocation?

Comment: pyinstaller --clean -F -d all MapViewer.spec