# Create standalone EXE PyQGIS application

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt5

Has anyone managed to create a separate PyQGIS exe application?

Versions: QGIS 3.22 or 3.28, Python 3.9, IDE PyCharm 2022.2

I've already tried almost everything, including the instructions from this discussion, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I put a more specific question in the discussion here: 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/455473/after-adding-the-line-from-qgis-core-import-qgsapplication-the-exe-applicatio
but so far it is still unanswered. So I wanted to generalize the problem.